# css - animation hover effect on background-image

Tags: css, background-image, css-transitions

I'm trying to add an animation effect on an image used as a `background` in css.

Here's the css:

```css
{
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150')no-repeat top center;"
  background-size: cover !important;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

a.mf-portfolio-image-container:hover{ 
  background-size: 120% !important;
  //transform: grow(1.072, 1.072);
  //-webkit-transform: scale(1.072, 1.072);
  //-moz-transform: scale(1.072, 1.072);
  //-ms-transform: scale(1.072, 1.072);
}
```

Now, on hover, I'm trying to scale the `background-size` a bit (grown effect) but it's not working.

All I have is the background increasing in size but without the animation (or anyway, scale it smoothly)

I've read some articles, but they are all talking about this effect applied not on `background-image`, but on an image in the HTML.

here's a quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edrucqjm/)

any idea on how to properly achieve this type of effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 things wrong in your code,

- ### 1st

you have an extra double quote `"` after the `background` which make the rest of the CSS below invalid, therefore the transition, won't work

- ### 2nd

you can't have `background-size:cover` and `background-size:100%` at the same time, it only parse the last one that was added in CSS.

#### Note:

Comment Syntax: in CSS this `//` doesn't work, use `/* */`

```css
.row {
  padding: 50px;
}
.mf-portfolio-page {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
a.mf-portfolio-image-container {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150')no-repeat top center;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
a.mf-portfolio-image-container:hover {
  background-size: 120%;
  /*transform: grow(1.072, 1.072);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.072, 1.072);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.072, 1.072);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.072, 1.072); */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 mf-portfolio-page">
    <a href="#" class="mf-portfolio-image-container">
      <div class="mf-portfolio-image-container-description">
        title
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but, apart from the code correction (the double quote is not in my code, but was a typo in the fiddle) and explaining about the background size, the animation still doesn't work...
it is not a smooth transition, so you aren't really answering my question to be honest :)

Comment: care to share a link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/edrucqjm/1/ - I tried with 1 second as animationfuration to check if it was working smoothly or not, but it's not. Thanks for your help, btw

Comment: @Nick it is working perfect, you just put 5s as transition, that will take a lot, try put . 0.5s

Comment: Can you creat a fiddle? on mine it still not working unfortunatelly. I can see that the size changes, but not slowly. I actually want it to be (you probably know the effect i'm talkin about) when you hover over an image, it grows a bit and adds a caption. the caption bit it's not the problem here tho. Thats, not the righ effects unfortunately, it is too fast and even with 5s transition nothing changes on my fiddle

Comment: it is doing exactly the same thing...https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/imagehovers/index.html check the example with the girl's face. I'm trying to achieve something like that, but that's not working with background-image

Comment: men, here is their code for transition `all 1s ease 0s` ... your code is working fine